# Send request at random times between two times

Tags: python, python-2.7, random-time-generation

If I wanted to do a command at a random time between two times how would I do this?

For example, send the following request at a random time between 10 seconds and 60 minutes?

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest implementation would be to make your program sleep for a random amount of time between 10 and 3600 seconds.

You can use the `time.sleep()` method to make your program pause and the `random.randint(x, y)` method to generate a random number between `x` and `y`

```
import time, random, requests

time.sleep(random.randint(10, 3600))
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

Comment: This would only do the request once, correct? Is there a way for it to keep doing the requests until I stop it?

Comment: That depends on how you'd like to stop it, but yes this will only make the requests call once

Comment: If you'd like to keep this running multiple times, you will need to create a loop and add some extra logic depending on how you'd like the script to stop

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `random` module

```
import random
import time

secondstowait = random.randint(10, 60)
minutestowait = random.randint(0, 59) * 60 # converts minutes to seconds

time.sleep(secondstowait + minutestowait)
```

the `sleep()` function from `time` module obviously stops your program for the requested amount of seconds

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways of doing this, you could try to use full featured libraries to avoid reinventing the wheel and that can fulfill more complex requirements. Since your example snippet is python, please take a look at [Simpy](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/latency.html).

It is an excellent full featured library things like your example to more complex full featured simulations.